# Groupwise maximum query for getting records for latest date

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to build a query that only gets the latest record on a group of records based on date.

The layout of the table is following:

```
| date | category | action | label | label2 | count_today | count_total | period |
```

The primary key is based on the columns `date`, `category`, `action`, `label`, `label2`, `period`. `date` has format `yyyy-mm-dd` and period can have the values `Day`, `Week`, `month`.

For each unique combination of `category | action | label | label2` I need to have the record with the latest date.

My first attempt at this was this:

```
SELECT * FROM `statistic` 
WHERE 
 (action='total' OR action='' OR category='user')
 AND
 (period='day' 
   OR (period='week' AND DATEDIFF(now(), `date`) > 30)
   OR (period = 'Month' AND DATEDIFF(now(), `date`) > 7*26)
 )
GROUP BY category, action, label, label2
ORDER BY date DESC
```

The problem with this query is that it does the GROUP BY before the ORDER BY, causing incorrect records to be returned.

After searching, I found that what I want is called a [group-wise maximum](http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html) query.

My next attempt was this:

```
SELECT s1.* FROM `statistic` AS s1
LEFT JOIN statistic AS s2 
ON 
 s1.category = s2.category
 AND s1.action = s2.action
 AND s1.label = s2.label
 AND s1.label2 = s2.label2
 AND s1.date > s2.date
WHERE 
   (s1.action='total' OR s1.action='' OR s1.category='user')
   AND
   (s1.period='day' 
   OR (s1.period='week' AND DATEDIFF(now(), s1.`date`) > 30)
   OR (s1.period = 'Month' AND DATEDIFF(now(), s1.`date`) > 7*26)
 )
GROUP BY category, action, label, label2
```

But this query doesn't give me the correct results either (it looks similar to the first query).

Any clue how I can get the data that I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that you want the [group-wise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), but you accomplish this by joining your table with a subquery that finds the latest date for each group:

```
SELECT * FROM statistic NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   category, action, label, label2, MAX(date) date
  FROM     statistic
  GROUP BY category, action, label, label2
) t
```

And then, if the following filters are still required:

```
WHERE 
 (action='total' OR action='' OR category='user')
 AND
 (period='day' 
   OR (period='week' AND DATEDIFF(now(), `date`) > 30)
   OR (period = 'Month' AND DATEDIFF(now(), `date`) > 7*26)
 )
```

Comment: No I wasn't refering to your answer. Deleted mine anyway, since yours is a bit more elegant.

Comment: Fair enough :)  I'm not convinced about your edit, though - as the question states "*For each unique combination of `category | action | label | label2` I need to have the record with the latest date.*" (I think those filters were applied by the OP in erroneous attempts to reach this solution).  I suggest at very least separating out into a separate query.

Comment: Fair enough, master of elegance :)

Comment: Those filters are needed (I don't actually need this for all records). This indeed gives the right results

Comment: @Ikke: Actually, if the filters are required they ought to be moved into the subquery (unless you genuinely wish to filter the grouped results rather than the records that constitute the groups).

Comment: @eggyal It doesn't seem to make a difference though.

Comment: Could use this answer again for a different problem. Thanks @eggyal